# !important CSS Attribute

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, octicons

I'm currently trying to get a buttons style working on Github.  It works through a chrome extension, and I'm also not terribly sure how to go about debugging Chrome Extensions.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
.octicon-class {
    background-image: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/');
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

I was considering using the `!important` declaration on some of the attributes in this method, but I've seen that it is bad style.  Is there a better way to get the button to appear (as opposed to just text)

Comment: It's all about [CSS specifity](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

Comment: Without knowing what HTML and existing CSS you are working with, it is really hard to help.

Comment: So would using !important to override the other selectors - or would that be considered bad style?

Comment: @kzisme It's considered bad style. Try to stay away from !important as much as possible. Only use it when you have no other option. Use specifity.

Comment: Here is the current HTML http://pastebin.com/weht021b

The button css is linked in the original post.

@user1129884 is there a decent way to figure out what's the best way to approach selectors and specificity?

Comment: @kzisme pbaldauf's linked URL does a decent job at explaining the concept.

Comment: On an unrelated note, use relative urls and omit the `chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/` part.